# How to link/sync complete Contact list with Google speech API (REST)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech, google-speech-api

I am currently working on speech to text conversion using Google speech REST API. The program is working and is giving me the text of the speech given. My use case is to convert the person's name (spoken) into text. For e.g. `"Rohan Chawhan"`.

**What have I observed:**

Now when I compared the results of Google Assistant (on Phone *(Android/iOS)*) and the Google speech REST API (on Linux PC) here is what I found:

**- When the Phone & Gmail Contacts are NOT synced.**
Both, Google Assistant and the Speech API shows me the same text which is incorrect (`"Rohan Chauhan"`). It is probably because `"Rohan Chauhan"` is more common than `"Rohan Chawhan"`, in India.

**- When the Phone or Gmail Contacts are synced.**
Google Assistant detects the name correctly `"Rohan Chawhan"` if it is present in the contact. Since in the Speech REST API shows me the same error text as above `"Rohan Chauhan"`

**What am I looking for:** 
Is there A way I can sync/upload/link a contact list/database/table of names for Google Speech API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Phrase hints 
see google documentation 
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints

Comment: Hi @syedirfan, Thanks for the input. But my concern on this would be that the JSON data (curl request) would grow with the contact list. Thus it is not economical to send all the contacts as "phrases" for each speech to text conversion. Any solution to this?

Comment: I believe this will be one time, you train your model once.

Comment: Hey I have tried adding this `,\"speechContexts\":[{\"phrases\":[\"Rohan\",\"Chawhan\",\"Rohan Chawhan\"]}]` in the curl request. Still, it recognizes the speech as `"Rohan Chauhan"`. What are the chances of getting a correct recognition with this method?

Comment: Hey, @syed I tried with a few more cases and found that the **phrases** method works most of the time. Although it does not work like what you said, I have to send the same f=phrases in each request which is not economical in my use case. Is there something better I can do?

Comment: Hello @RC0993 unable to found, let me know if you found any solution

Comment: yes absolutely, By now I am actually almost convinced that google assistant tries to find the best match in the phone directory locally and the the speech to text c9nversion is actually un altered

Comment: yes, it seems like that, I started working on GCP speech API a few days back it's very hard almost impossible  to find a solution